# Copying a file with cp is stuck (copying with Dolphin doesn't finish either)

Tags: debian, usb, kde, cp, file-copy

I had a problem with copying files from my hard drive to an USB stick with the Dolphin file-manager in Debian11/KDE. Some were stuck near the middle and some were stuck after the full file-size was copied. I aborted the copying of the full-file-size files (pressed stop) but the hashsum differed so it didn't copy completely and the mp4 file only played until a certain point before half of the file.

Today, I deleted the files on the USB stick and tried again. I could copy over all of the same mp4 files but one and this time the checksums for the copied files matched. The copying of these files was still displayed as stuck after the full file was copied (pressed stop). I then tried to copy the file whose checksum differed using the `cp` command. However, it got suck...or to be more precise the transfer speed dropped to near zero (maybe 10 KB/s) after half of the file was copied over. I could not abort the bash command in the konsole using ctrl+C so I had to kill the bash process (just killing the cp one wasn't enough) with the task manager.

-> **Where can I see what `cp`'s (or Dolphin's) problems with the copying are?**

Are there logs somewhere, is there a verbose mode, is there a good way to debug this issue, or is this (or rather these problems) a known issue?

---

Now I compared the checksums again and now all files have different checksums. Don't know why and I haven't plugged it in anywhere else then I tried copying the second time. I [can't use gparted in wayland](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gparted/-/issues/208) to check the USB stick's filesystem, and `sudo fdisk -l` does not list it but `mount` displays that it is `vfat`. I had some problems with copying over files before but I think it was because the USB stick turned to readonly and this was usually solved by formatting and remaking its filesystem in gparted and I never had such problems when copying. I tried the cp command a third time (to another target filename) and now the new file-size was instantaneously the full file-size of 0.5 GB but the copying is still stuck anyway. I tried it again and the same thing happened and even the checksums match but it's still stuck anyway.

Comment: A 'wear' problem with the thumb drives flash cells would probably show in the ```dmesg``` output. I also suggest using ```rsync``` to copy the files, because a second invocation continues previously interrupted transfers.

Comment: No file gets copied when I run `rsync "file1.mp4" "usbdir/"` and there's no console output.

Comment: Check what `dmesg` says, as Anick pointed out.

Comment: I'd bet that your "good" copy is just in memory and it failed to actually get written to the usb stick.  The reason it doesn't finish is because it is waiting for the OS to acknowledge that the write completed....which it can't because it is failing.  If you cant interrupt it with ctrl-c it might be stuck in uninterruptible disk wait.

Comment: @MarcusMüller dmesg says nothing after running rsync and cp commands, only `FAT-fs (sdx1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.`. With rsync no file is there but with cp a file is there and can get played.

Comment: Yeah forget about rsync vs cp, probably just cached file writes. You need to unmount and check the integrity of your file system asap. No, actually, your description literally says this stick has lost data before. You need to try restore the data from the stick, and get a new one, ideally a different type.

Comment: There is no data on it and these problems were long ago and it still worked fine until these things happened (and some files get copied). GParted doesn't start for the reason I linked. Is there a GUI that runs without root in Wayland to do this? And there should still be some error message or similar when running cp (or copying in Dolphin) if this is the problem and it should be able to abort the copying with ctrl+c.

Comment: How long are you waiting for this to finish and how much data are you copying?  It is possible there is absolutely nothing wrong except that you hit ctrl-c and/or pulled out the USB before writes were finished.

Comment: Usually it takes around 20 seconds to copy the 0.5 GB but as said it also copied it over instantaneously two times (at most 1 s). When I waited I left it for a few minutes and the size only grew by maybe 1 MB, something like 200 MB to 201 MB. I could view the partition with KDE Partition manager now, it's FAT32. I deleted it and remade the partition. Then I ran the same `cp` command and it copied the file over completely but was stuck near the end, waited for a min and it completed. Maybe there are problems with writing some metadata. But if that is the case there should be output/way to debug

Comment: If you actually eject the usb either from command line or GUI, it should be able to finish writing everything.  It's hard to say from this if you've corrupted the filesystem by pulling out too soon (which formatting would fix) or if it's a hardware issue.

Comment: The issue is still there after remaking the filesystem in KDE Partition Manager, it may have improved because it finishes copying after waiting for 1 minute after the full file-size has been copied. It seems to be having problems with the finish process such as writing some metadata - this is why I'd like to have some output to see or debug what its problems are.

Comment: Are you ejecting it in software before pulling it out physically?

Comment: Usually I do, iirc it sometimes just didn't work. In any case, the issue is still there even after remaking the FAT32 partition with KDE Partition Manager. The question is basically about how to get some output to see or debug what the copying problems are.

Comment: If ejecting "doesn't work" then probably either something is still using the drive, or data is still being written to it.   If something is using it, `sudo fuser -m /mount/point` (replace mount opint...) should tell you what is using it.  If there are actual errors, they should show up in your system logs (`dmesg` or /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages usually).